# Play sound when clicking image

Tags: java, android, soundpool

Ive got an image that needs to play a .wav file when you click it. But the app doesnt start at all. I dont know why because it looks i declared all things it needs. But when i start the app it crashes right away

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private SoundPool soundPool;
  private int soundID;
  boolean loaded = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    view.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);
    // Set the hardware buttons to control the music
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // Load the sound
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
      @Override
      public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
          int status) {
        loaded = true;
      }
    });
    soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.koe, 1);

  }

  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      // Getting the user sound settings
      AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
      float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
          .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
          .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
      // Is the sound loaded already?
      if (loaded) {
        soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
        Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

**EDIT**

i think you have to do Like this way

```
// Declare as global variable 
  WebView mWebview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayoutfile);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Laden van roosterwijzigingen.",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mWebview =(WebView) findviewById(R.id.webview_id);
        // Enable JavaScript
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
        mWebview.loadUrl("http://divers.ommelandercollege.nl/webportalen/dagrooster.php");

      }
```

LOGCAT

```
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.flikkema.robin.vleesapp/org.flikkema.robin.vleesapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.flikkema.robin.vleesapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnTouchListener
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.flikkema.robin.vleesapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnTouchListener
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at org.flikkema.robin.vleesapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-24 19:46:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(10368):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` in your `onCreate()` before calling `findViewById()`

Otherwise it doesn't know what layout to look for when you are trying to inflate your `ImageView`.

So:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); // <--- HERE, ADD THIS
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Replace `your_layout` with the actual name of your .xml layout file.

Comment: Post the crash log please, and we'll be better able to assist you.

Comment: Change to this `view.setOnTouchListener(this);` (remove the cast to OnTouchListener) and make your Activity implement OnTouchListener, so `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: And then? i can  find the cast, and i dont know what i need to change to view.setOnTouchListener(this); but ive added the implents ontouch thingy

Comment: Change line 3 of `onCreate` to `view.setOnTouchListener(this);` and make your MainActivity class implement `OnTouchListener`.

Comment: I ve followed your advice and it did fix it

Comment: Great stuff! Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

And after doing what ken wolf said you can do this to play sound when an image is clicked

```
     MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.myMusic);
    imageClickable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
      mp.start();
  }

});
```

Hope it helps